# Is there a way to use print with the formats of printf in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

On my quest to acquire further experience in Haskell, I started working with print and printf.

I wanted to try to print an array (well, several, but it's just a start) and I wanted to use the format `"%+.4f"`, meaning I would get:

```
+2.1234 or -1.2345
```

I noticed however that it's pretty hard to print an array using printf, so I tried switching to print. It seems easier to print a list this way, but I'm not sure how I can print the elements of the list using the same format I used for printf.

My list looks something like this:

```
[-1.2, 2.3, 4.7, -6.850399]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two variants that should do the same, using the two possible return types of printf:

```
putStrLn $ concatMap (printf "%+.4f\n") [-1.2, 2.3, 4.7, -6.850399]
mapM_ (printf "%+.4f\n") [-1.2, 2.3, 4.7, -6.850399]
```

Edit: For traversing two lists deep:

```
putStrLn $ (concatMap . concatMap) (printf "%+.4f\n") [[-1.2, 2.3], [4.7, -6.850399]]
(mapM_ . mapM_) (printf "%+.4f\n") [[-1.2, 2.3], [4.7, -6.850399]]
```

Comment: Is there a way I can apply this to a list of lists? Say for example [[-1.2, 2.3], [4.7, -6.899]]. I'm pretty sure map would not work cause I would map something that is printed to some lists.

Comment: I found a solution, but it doesn't actually use your implementation. I would still be interested to learn how you can print the list of lists I posted above, though (using any of your solutions).

Comment: Use `mapM_ (mapM_ (printf ...))` to print a list of lists.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the functions in the `Numeric` module.  For instance "%+.4f" can be represented as

```
formatFloat x = showFFloat (Just 4) x ""
```

You can then map this function over your list, to get a list of Strings.

```
> map formatFloat [-1.2, 2.3, 4.7, -6.850399]
["-1.2000","2.3000","4.7000","-6.8504"]
```

(since these are already strings I'd use `putStrLn` instead of `print` to show the output.)

Comment: That doesn't actually do what "%+.4f" does as it won't show the "+" for the positive numbers.