# Using "printf" on a list in Haskell

Tags: haskell, printf

How can i use `printf` over a list?
I have a list of numbers and i want to print them all by respecting a format (ex: `%.3f`). I tried to use map over `printf`, but it does not work. So, i have no idea. Can somebody help me with this? Any ideas are acceptable. Is there a way to create a string from a list respecting a custom format?

Comment: can you please add what you tried - because I would indeed recommend using `map` and I don't see why it should not work

Comment: possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36658890/is-there-a-way-to-use-print-with-the-formats-of-printf-in-haskell

Comment: the result of `printf` is polymorphic and can't be decided without context, try add more type signatures.

Comment: then please edit your question and add an answer or close/delete it - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf` can produce strings instead of just printing them to stdout. This
is because it is overloaded on its result type (it's also part of machinery
that makes it variadic).

```hs
import Text.Printf

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn . unwords $ printf "%.3f" <$> ([1..10] :: [Double])
```

That should do the trick.

---

BTW, `printf` is not type safe and can blow at run time. I recommend you use
something like
[`formatting`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/formatting).